# Generic relation in django, queryset with aggregate

Tags: python, django, aggregate, django-1.6, django-generic-relations

I use django 1.6 and generic relation in models. And I have problem with `aggregate` function in model:

Here is part of my view:

```
class EventListView(PageContextMixin, ListView):
    model = Activity
    template_name = 'events/eventlist.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        seasons = Season.objects.all()
        if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
            seasons = seasons.filter(is_active=True)
            active_seasons_ids = list(IsActiveFlag.objects.exclude(is_active=False).values_list('id', flat=True))
            seasons = list(Season.objects.filter(isactiveflags__id__in=active_seasons_ids))
        minmax = seasons.aggregate(Min('start'), Max('end'))
        min_date = minmax['start__min']
        max_date = minmax['end__max']

        active_sale_and_cycles_ids = list(SaleAndCycle.objects.exclude(is_sale_active=False).values_list('id', flat=True))
        filters_sale = Q(sale_and_cycles__id__in=active_sale_and_cycles_ids)
        active_is_cyclic_event_ids = list(SaleAndCycle.objects.exclude(is_cyclic_event_active=False).values_list('id', flat=True))
        filters_cycle = Q(sale_and_cycles__id__in=active_is_cyclic_event_ids)
        sales_events_activities = Activity.objects.filter(Q(filters_sale, online=True) | Q(filters_cycle, online=True))   
        sales_events_ids = sales_events_activities.values_list('id', flat=True)
        minmax_sales_events_activities = sales_events_activities.aggregate(Min('start'), Max('end'))
        max_date_sales_events_activities = minmax_sales_events_activities['end__max']
```

I get an error in this place:

```
minmax_sales_events_activities = sales_events_activities.aggregate(Min('start'), Max('end'))
```

Error:

```
no such table: events_saleandcycle
```

But there is table in database (I use sqlite) with fields: id, content_type_id, object_id, position, is_sale_active, is_cyclic_event_active, cycle_link

```
class SaleAndCycle(SortableVAExtra):
    is_sale_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_cyclic_event_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    cycle_link = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.is_sale_active)
```

Comment: Can you show your Activity model?

Comment: what django 1.6 are you using? What's the minor version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [closed issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10461) against Django 1.6 that describes failures of annotations (aggregations). The [relevant commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/76da053641e52db540801e18b362497c01e9bb1d) with the fix is only present in Django 1.7a upwards.

I fear your only chance is to upgrade to Django 1.7.

Comment: I remembered having problems with annotations back in 1.6